# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I've been stuck with this error for a few days and am not able to find where the mistake is.

views section

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth

# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        username=request.POST['username']
        password1=request.POST['password1']
        password2=request.POST['password2']
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password1)
        user.save();
        print("user created")
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request,'registration.html')
```

urls.py section

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns=[path('register/',views.register,name="register")]
```

html section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        USERNAME  <input type="text" name="username" id=""> <br><br>
        PASSWORD  <input type="password" name="password1" id=""> <br><br>
        RETYPE PASSWORD  <input type="password" name="password2" id=""> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="">    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

1. `create_user()` doesn't require `save()` method to be called for creating instance.
2. You have given only `action="register"` which is not valid at all, you need to give `url` tag, to perfectly make route. That's the case for page not found which is the main question.

So, with some modifications try below code:

Views.py

```py
def register(request):
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        username=request.POST['username']
        password1=request.POST['password1']
        password2=request.POST['password2']
        user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password1)
        print("user created")
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request,'registration.html')
```

Template file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        USERNAME  <input type="text" name="username" id=""> <br><br>
        PASSWORD  <input type="password" name="password1" id=""> <br><br>
        RETYPE PASSWORD  <input type="password" name="password2" id=""> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `create_user` is a perfectly valid method on the builtin `User` model (See [GitHub code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L158)). Not using that method in fact causes errors for multiple people (`.save()` or `.create()` will not hash your password causing the authenticate method to fail)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, you are right, but the OP was satisfied with this answer, and it has been deleted by diamond moderators when I commented on MSO post , I think  you also come from there, the OP replied something like thankyou sir the error is cleared now. And I know, the password will not be hashed by default, but that doesn't asked, password can also be hashed through `make_password()` which is at `from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password`.