# Django create user command issue while trying to add a new user through a html form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have successfully created a table in the database and can add data from the admin panel onto the table but when i used the form displayed on a url by clicking submit a new user is not created.

**views.py:**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from formRegister.models import FormRegister
    
    # Create your views here.
    
    def register(request):
            

     if request.method == 'post':
                
                first_name = request.POST['fisrt_name']
                last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                username = request.POST['username']
                                                
                user = FormRegister.objects.create_user(username=username, first_name=first_name, 
 last_name=last_name)
                user.save(commit = True);
               
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                return render (request, 'formRegister.html')
    **models.py**
```

This is the code for the model.py section

```
    from distutils.command.upload import upload
    from django.db import models
    from .models import FormRegister
    
    # Create your models here.
   
    class FormRegister(models.Model):
        firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   
**# admin.py**
```

Below is the code for the admin.py section
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import FormRegister

```
# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(FormRegister)

urls.py
```

This is the urls.py section of the code
from django.urls import path
from formRegister import views

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("register", views.register, name="register"),
]
```

Below is the form created in a template folder named formRegister.html
**# formRegister.html**

```
    <form action="register" method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First_Name"> <br>
             <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last_Name"> <br>
             <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"> <br>
             <input type="Submit" value="Submit"> <br>
        </form>
    <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Show yours FormRegister class. Btw you omitting .is_valid() function on form. Oh and FormRegister is django form or model?

Comment: This is normal model not Django based user model. Just use create instead of create_user. Why you name model 'Form' this is confusing

Comment: First thing, `create_user` doesn't require save method to be called and `username` and `password` are necessary, you haven't give the password, refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72122072/17562044) answer for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if request.method == 'post':` to `if request.method == 'POST':`

Change `<input type="Submit" value="Submit">` to `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Omit `user.save(commit = True);`